# Unit test Cases for infinite loops

Tags: java, mockito, amazon-sqs

I have a similar piece of code for reading all the messages from a SQS queue

```
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(myQueueUrl);
receiveMessageRequest.withMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
while (messages.size() > 0) {
    for (final Message message : messages) {
        System.out.println("Message");
        System.out.println("  MessageId:     " + message.getMessageId());
        System.out.println("  ReceiptHandle: " + message.getReceiptHandle());
        System.out.println("  MD5OfBody:     " + message.getMD5OfBody());
        System.out.println("  Body:          " + message.getBody());
        for (final Entry<String, String> entry : message.getAttributes().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Attribute");
            System.out.println("  Name:  " + entry.getKey());
            System.out.println("  Value: " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(myQueueUrl);
    receiveMessageRequest.withMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
    messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
}
```

Link: [How to fetch all messages from SQS queue till the queue is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432276/how-to-fetch-all-messages-from-sqs-queue-till-the-queue-is-empty)

In the unit test cases, I have mocked the message list to list created for the testing

```
@Mock
ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult;
.
.
.
when(receiveMessageResult.getMessages()).thenReturn(messageList);
```

I am having problems in testing this since the loop is infinite for a hard-coded list in test cases due to the re-assignation of the variable messages.

Is there a way to decrease this variable only for test cases?

PS: Found similar question to this topic but they did not cover my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain thenReturn-calls, like so:

```
when(receiveMessageResult.getMessages()).thenReturn(messageList).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
```

Comment: Thanks, Did'nt know about this. So every time the method is invoked it returns the next item in chain?

Comment: @Falcon exactly.